# How create condition to relations Yii

Tags: yii

I have relations in Yii:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'applicant' => array(
                self::BELONGS_TO,
                'ApplicantProfile',
                array('applicant_id' => 'id'),
            ),
            'filePair' => array(
                self::BELONGS_TO,
                'DocumentCategoryFile',
                array('file_pair_id' => 'id'),
                'joinType' => 'inner join'
            )
        );
    }
```

How i can create `addCondition` in `CDbCriteria()` for aplicant, for example i want do `is_deleted = 0`. I am tried it `$criteria->with = array('applicant' => array('join'=>'left join','condition'=>'`aplicant`.is_deleted = 0'));` but i have sql syntax error
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
          $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
          $criteria->with = array('applicant');
          $criteria->together = true;
          $criteria->addCondition('applicant.is_deleted=0');
```

You should refer the link [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) to learn how to use it.

Comment: Only just found a similar solution. Thanks its right answer